# Cannot find module providing package

Tags: go, go-modules

I'm not sure how to solve a dependency issue I'm finding with "go mod". From what I could gather, it's fetching the wrong version of some sub-dependency which points to a repo that doesn't exist anymore.

I very very new to go so I'm sure I'm screwing up, I'd love some help to understand how to fix this. Please check these examples:

**Getting my only dependency with go get works fine**

```
export GOPATH=`mktemp -d`
export MYAPP=`mktemp -d`
cd $MYAPP

cat << EOF > main.go
package main
import (
  "fmt"
  "os"
  "github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pkg/storage"
)
func main() {
  if err := storage.StartStorageProvisioner(); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error starting provisioner: %v\n", err)
    os.Exit(1)
  }
}
EOF

go get github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pkg/storage
go build && echo "WORKED" || echo "FAILED"
```

**However, getting it with go mod doesn't work**

```
export GOPATH=`mktemp -d`
export MYAPP=`mktemp -d`
cd $MYAPP

cat << EOF > main.go
package main
import (
  "fmt"
  "os"
  "github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pkg/storage"
)
func main() {
  if err := storage.StartStorageProvisioner(); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error starting provisioner: %v\n", err)
    os.Exit(1)
  }
}
EOF

go mod init github/my/repo
go build && echo "WORKED" || echo "FAILED"
```

How do I get this last one working?

```
$ go version
go version go1.12 darwin/amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Go modules wiki](http://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules)

> Day-to-day upgrading and downgrading of dependencies should be done using 'go get', which will automatically update the go.mod file. Alternatively, you can edit go.mod directly.

To the extent that I've understood go mod init won't go get your dependencies, rather it'll initialize a new module and create a mod file to track the dependency versions that your module is using.

So go getting your dependencies is fine.

Go modules on the other hand **will** according to the wiki again provide certain functionalities:

> Standard commands like **go build** or **go test** will automatically add new dependencies as needed to satisfy imports (updating go.mod and downloading the new dependencies).
>
> When needed, more specific versions of dependencies can be chosen with
>   commands such as go get foo@v1.2.3, go get foo@master, go get
>   foo@e3702bed2, or by editing go.mod directly.

Comment: I though that getting your dependencies was its whole deal. The example that they have is very similar to mine except that they depend on rsc.io/quote. Go mod works that example but not for mine because of the issue I explained on the question. I'm looking for a way to handle that case or the correct way to get that main.go working with go mod instead of go get.

Comment: I see I ran the code in my own machine it seems like github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/lib/leaderelection doesn't seem to exist anymore. In the documentation for kubernetes-incubator they mention that the /lib/ package has been deprecated and moved. It seems like the change has made something in the dependency chain break. I don't know how to fix this or if you even can, it sounds more like an issue on the part of the user of the lib/leaderelection package.

Comment: If it works for you with go get you might have a previous version with this package still intact in your goroot or gopath you might wanna consider vendoring all the dependencies and manually adding it to the vendor folder until there is a fix available. Sadly I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: each example initializes a new GOPATH with mktemp to avoid that kind of mixup. Regardless, you can run both examples in a docker container and get the same result so it doesn't look like an environment specific issue. Thanks for helping!